# How can we get accurate latitude,longitude in PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to get accurate latitude and longitude using PhoneGap but i'm unable to get accurate lat,long it always fluctuate after third decimal point means it gives 11m difference as describe here:
decimal
places   degrees          distance
-------  -------          --------
0        1                111  km
1        0.1              11.1 km
2        0.01             1.11 km
3        0.001            111  m
4        0.0001           11.1 m
5        0.00001          1.11 m

For getting lat,long in phonegap i am using geolocation plugin with gpsdetect plugin.

Here is code:
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy:true});
 function onSuccess(position)
    {
     window.lat=position.coords.latitude;
     window.long=position.coords.longitude;
     var accuracy=position.coords.accuracy;
     var lat = (window.lat).toFixed(6);
     var long = (window.long).toFixed(6);
     document.getElementById('lat').value=lat;
     document.getElementById('long').value=long;
     document.getElementById('accuracy').value=accuracy;
    }
 function onGPSError(e)
    {
     console.log("Error : "+e);
    }

using this code i am getting (22.699737,75.867208) but in actual it is (22.699667,75.86729).

I just want to get location based on gps not from cell tower and wifi signal.

Is it posible in phonegap to get location only by GPS when gps is on?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please see also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy:true})

Comment: Thanks Martin i am using: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy:true})    function onSuccess(position)
    {
     window.lat=position.coords.latitude;
     window.long=position.coords.longitude;
     var accuracy=position.coords.accuracy;
     var lat = (window.lat).toFixed(6);
     var long = (window.long).toFixed(6);
    alert(lat+','+long);
    } and I want to get lat,long only if gps is enabled not through wifi or  cell signals.Please suggest me.

Comment: Do not post comments with poorly formatted content. Instead, *improve your question*. This makes it more likely that you get more answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery geocode to get lat long from address.

pass your location(address) from GPs & call this jquery function you 'll get perfect lat,long.

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            title: results[0].formatted_address
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: address });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () { infowindow.open(map, marker); });
    } 
    else{
        alert("Problem with geolocation");
    }
});
```

Convert Address to Latitude Longtitude :
https://github.com/dhavaldenny/mapgeocodeangular